# Calculus problem finding minimum of integral.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$M$ be the set of continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that  $e^{f(x)}+f(x) \geq x+1$ for all x in $\mathbb{R}$ and for all $f$ in M. Find the minimum of $I(f) =\int_0^e f(x) dx$. Any hint please.

Answer (score 0):

Set $g(y) = e^y + y$. Then the functions in $M$ satisfy $g(f(x))\ge x+1$. Since $g$ is increasing, its inverse $g^{-1}$ is increasing, too, and so $f(x)\ge g^{-1}(x+1)$. Thus, the minimum value is $I=\int_0^e g^{-1}(x+1)\,dx$. You don't have to know $g^{-1}$ to compute that integral. Substitute $x=g(y)-1$ to get $I=\int_0^1 y(e^y+1)\,dy$. Integration by parts:
$$
I = y(e^y+y)\big|_0^1 - \int_0^1(e^y+y)\,dy = \frac 32.
$$